# A different approach on accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

So here's the scenario: I am fixing a site that has 25-30 pages utilizing this kind of approach of accordion (http://jsbin.com/uqosap/6). This is my javascript approach for the accordion since i'm stuck with html structure that is being used to 25-30 pages and I don't want want to messup the CSS. So instead, I'll just put a javascript on top of it so it would function like an accordion.

My Problem:

1. When headers are clicked it doesn't align to the top, so you would have to scroll down so you can see the content of the accordion. Once click, the header should auto-align on top so the content would be visible on screen.
2. I messed-up adding my `if` condition for the class. It doesn't function the way I want it. It should apply a class 'enabled' for the header that is currently active, and the rest would have a 'disable' class.

I would gladly appreciate any help.

Thank You.

[edit]

**Here's what I did for the javascript.**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.accordion .hdr:first').next().stop(false,true).slideDown(1000);
      $('.accordion .hdr:first').addClass('enable')
      $('.accordion .hdr').click(function(){
        $('.accordion .content').hide();
        $('.accordion .hdr').addClass('disable');
        $(this).next().stop(false,true).slideDown(1000);
        $(this).find(".aj_a").css({"background-position":"0 -43px","width":"20px","height":"15px","margin-right":"1px"}) 

         if($(this).hasClass('disable')) {
            $(this).addClass('enable');
         }
         else {
            $('.accordion .hdr').addClass('disable');
            $(this).addClass('enable');
          }

      });    
    });

  </script>
```

**and this is the structure for the html.**

```
  <ul class="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="hdr">heading 1</div>
      <div class="content"><p><strong>Heading 1 Content:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pellentesque rhoncus diam sollicitudin porta. Aliquam condimentum nibh a massa ultrices tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent neque mauris, adipiscing a vulputate non, laoreet a est. Integer tincidunt, enim ac tempor imperdiet, libero purus hendrerit risus, sit amet tristique leo nisi sed erat. Donec sit amet eleifend arcu. Ut placerat lacinia malesuada.

Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum felis lacus, tincidunt a semper et, accumsan eu urna. Mauris pharetra facilisis tellus dapibus ultricies. Suspendisse non turpis sit amet nisl dictum egestas. Mauris sagittis elit eu felis commodo posuere. Nullam velit leo, porttitor sit amet faucibus at, mollis a purus. Maecenas varius dui nec ligula imperdiet sit amet gravida orci sagittis.

Fusce mi sem, luctus ut faucibus vel, hendrerit quis diam. Fusce ut metus felis, volutpat mattis nisi. Ut luctus quam a libero euismod eleifend. Aliquam at quam vel risus semper laoreet. Maecenas non velit dolor. Praesent in odio eget urna faucibus condimentum vel at ante. Aliquam non purus nec odio lacinia ornare. Fusce luctus tellus sed leo tristique cursus. Phasellus dapibus tempor nunc nec euismod. Proin est nulla, feugiat eu tempor vel, iaculis sed lorem. Donec dictum viverra libero, eu fermentum arcu imperdiet eu. Nullam ultricies, tellus ut fermentum consectetur, mauris eros fermentum lacus, ac tincidunt magna nulla et libero. Fusce laoreet cursus magna sit amet rutrum. Ut mollis interdum nunc, at pulvinar mauris auctor gravida. Nullam faucibus massa ut dolor eleifend nec molestie velit consectetur. In augue nibh, rhoncus eget consectetur ac, posuere nec lorem.</p></div>
    </li>


    <li>
      <div class="hdr">heading 2</div>
      <div class="content"><p><strong>Heading 2 Content:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pellentesque rhoncus diam sollicitudin porta. Aliquam condimentum nibh a massa ultrices tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent neque mauris, adipiscing a vulputate non, laoreet a est. Integer tincidunt, enim ac tempor imperdiet, libero purus hendrerit risus, sit amet tristique leo nisi sed erat. Donec sit amet eleifend arcu. Ut placerat lacinia malesuada.

Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum felis lacus, tincidunt a semper et, accumsan eu urna. Mauris pharetra facilisis tellus dapibus ultricies. Suspendisse non turpis sit amet nisl dictum egestas. Mauris sagittis elit eu felis commodo posuere. Nullam velit leo, porttitor sit amet faucibus at, mollis a purus. Maecenas varius dui nec ligula imperdiet sit amet gravida orci sagittis.

Fusce mi sem, luctus ut faucibus vel, hendrerit quis diam. Fusce ut metus felis, volutpat mattis nisi. Ut luctus quam a libero euismod eleifend. Aliquam at quam vel risus semper laoreet. Maecenas non velit dolor. Praesent in odio eget urna faucibus condimentum vel at ante. Aliquam non purus nec odio lacinia ornare. Fusce luctus tellus sed leo tristique cursus. Phasellus dapibus tempor nunc nec euismod. Proin est nulla, feugiat eu tempor vel, iaculis sed lorem. Donec dictum viverra libero, eu fermentum arcu imperdiet eu. Nullam ultricies, tellus ut fermentum consectetur, mauris eros fermentum lacus, ac tincidunt magna nulla et libero. Fusce laoreet cursus magna sit amet rutrum. Ut mollis interdum nunc, at pulvinar mauris auctor gravida. Nullam faucibus massa ut dolor eleifend nec molestie velit consectetur. In augue nibh, rhoncus eget consectetur ac, posuere nec lorem.</p></div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="hdr">heading 3</div>
      <div class="content"><p><strong>Heading 3 Content:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pellentesque rhoncus diam sollicitudin porta. Aliquam condimentum nibh a massa ultrices tincidunt. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent neque mauris, adipiscing a vulputate non, laoreet a est. Integer tincidunt, enim ac tempor imperdiet, libero purus hendrerit risus, sit amet tristique leo nisi sed erat. Donec sit amet eleifend arcu. Ut placerat lacinia malesuada.

Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum felis lacus, tincidunt a semper et, accumsan eu urna. Mauris pharetra facilisis tellus dapibus ultricies. Suspendisse non turpis sit amet nisl dictum egestas. Mauris sagittis elit eu felis commodo posuere. Nullam velit leo, porttitor sit amet faucibus at, mollis a purus. Maecenas varius dui nec ligula imperdiet sit amet gravida orci sagittis.

Fusce mi sem, luctus ut faucibus vel, hendrerit quis diam. Fusce ut metus felis, volutpat mattis nisi. Ut luctus quam a libero euismod eleifend. Aliquam at quam vel risus semper laoreet. Maecenas non velit dolor. Praesent in odio eget urna faucibus condimentum vel at ante. Aliquam non purus nec odio lacinia ornare. Fusce luctus tellus sed leo tristique cursus. Phasellus dapibus tempor nunc nec euismod. Proin est nulla, feugiat eu tempor vel, iaculis sed lorem. Donec dictum viverra libero, eu fermentum arcu imperdiet eu. Nullam ultricies, tellus ut fermentum consectetur, mauris eros fermentum lacus, ac tincidunt magna nulla et libero. Fusce laoreet cursus magna sit amet rutrum. Ut mollis interdum nunc, at pulvinar mauris auctor gravida. Nullam faucibus massa ut dolor eleifend nec molestie velit consectetur. In augue nibh, rhoncus eget consectetur ac, posuere nec lorem.</p></div>
    </li>


  </ul>
```

Comment: Care to share some code for us to be able to help you?

Comment: Follow the link in the description. :)

Comment: I know but some code here on SO is advised

Comment: sorry would do that. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the scrolling I would prefer the jQuery plugin [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). Then add the callback `function() { $.scrollTo($(this)); }` as second parameter to the `.slideDown(1000)`.
2. Add a `.removeClass('disable')` before `.addClass('enable')`.

Also see your [updated code](http://jsbin.com/uqosap/11/edit#preview).

Comment: Thanks, I've also tried it. It's great but I find the scrolling to top  a bit weird. I think it needs to first scroll before sliding. I'll try to play around with it. Thank You!

Comment: Any idea why isn't this possible? 

$(this).next().stop(false,true).$.scrollTo($(this)).slideDown(1000).

Comment: You mean `$.scrollTo($(this)); $(this).next().stop(false,true).slideDown(1000);`? See [updated code](http://jsbin.com/uqosap/12/edit#preview).

Comment: The problem is that before the `.slideDown()` has finished the final height is unknown and the scrolling hasn't finished. So I put it to the callback in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4463/discussion-between-pennf0lio-and-scessor)